# run angular application on https on local with nginx using docker

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I run the angular application on nginx using docker. i also want to run it on https on local with nginx by create a host name entry on hostfile and run this with https.
I want to map localhost with domain name by creating an entry in hostfile & run it on https on local with nginx. Can anybody please help me.

Comment: It is a rather wide question. It can be done in several ways, automatic or manual. I use this stack to run angular locally, but it is not part of the question, to write guide how to build this infrastructure. I have used this article to build it on my own https://medium.com/@tiangolo/angular-in-docker-with-nginx-supporting-environments-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-bb9f1724e984

Answer (score 0):

> First of all I add a docker-compose.yml in the root of the project –

[image]

Then I add a default.conf file inside a folder nginx in the root of the project –

[image]

Then I create a nginx.dockerfile in the root of the project –

[image]

After that I run the command - docker-compose up –d

And run it on https on local.
we can map localhost with domain name by creating an entry in hostfile

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
[open host file with administration ]
add an entry like this-
127.0.0.1 ssldocker.test

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work for met. I got this exception: Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:problems making Certificate Request